# Email Newsletter - Layout goes weird in gmail

Tags: gmail, html-email, mailchimp

I created a newsletter for MailChimp. All looks good when I put it in the mailchimp website.

However when I send a test email to myself, some parts of the layout goes wrong in Gmail.

Some content goes too left and other content goes too right. While the header and some parts at the bottom is in the right place. It looks fine on my Phone.

My Newsletter Code: http://pastie.org/private/cwvosox7nzezqif7r3myoq

A picture of the problem i'm getting in Gmail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlZne.jpg

Can you please help me fix how its displayed in Gmail?
Thank you!

Comment: For further information, look at this [css support table](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). You may check, if you've used some techniques gmail doesn't actually support.

Comment: Is it the align="left"? If it is, how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: No, the html attribute `align` should have fairly good support even in html emails. Which browser do you use?

Comment: I'm using Firefox, but I get the same result in IE

Comment: Maybe you should try removing all not working parts and add them again one by one and test every step in between with test mails.

Comment: @RubyA Did you solve this problem? I have exactly the same problem, this only happens with Gmail. I've tried inserting everything inline but it doesn't change anything. Its quite, urgent..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the width of your page is bigger than gmail's div ...
Or kleinfreund idea  also have a good point.

Comment: He should try and resize the window with your newsletter preview in MailChimp

Comment: My width is 534px. I don't understand why its ok for the header but those certain areas go wrong

Comment: @RubyA Also note that you'll have to set the width on all container tds: `<td width="534">`

Answer (score 0):

edit: I just re-read, looks like this is your own html. Your display problems are directly related to the styles being in your head.

The code that you are displaying above has everything in the head, gmail does not recognize anything between the `<head></head>` tags.

You will need to move all of your css into inline styles

Comment: Actually, if using MailChimp, it should be automatically inlining the CSS. However, I don't 100% trust it, so I do always pull my CSS inline on my own, but MailChimp does have a tool to help with this process: http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css